# Why two kernel module copies are required in a linux kernel debug package installed system?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel-module, debug-symbols

In a Linux machine with kernel debug packages installed, I could see that two copies of kernel modules are there in two locations as mentioned below:

1. `/lib/modules/<$KERNELVERSION>/kernel/`
2. `/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/<$KERNELVERSION>/kernel/`

I do have a doubt that which module will be executed and what is the need for two modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `/lib/modules/<$KERNELVERSION>/kernel/` - modules, that will be loaded with kernel ( they are without debug symbols )

Example:

`ll /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/fs/xfs/xfs.ko

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1883966 Apr 24  2018 /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/fs/xfs/xfs.ko`

2. `/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/<$KERNELVERSION>/kernel/` - modules with debug symbols

Example:

`ll /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/fs/xfs/xfs.ko

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40247182 Apr 24  2018 /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/fs/xfs/xfs.ko`

As you can see, it's 1.8Mb vs 40Mb. If you compare outputs of `readelf -S <module>`, then you will notice additional sections like `debug_aranges`, `debug_info`, `debug_ranges`, etc. in debug module

Comment: ok. But where is the debug kernel module used? If the loaded kernel module is from /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/, what is the use of keeping a debug kernel module in /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/.

Comment: Debug kernel modules are used with commands like `crash`, `kgdb`, etc.